# executing centos commands from php script

Tags: php, scripting, exec, centos

I am working on a centos server and i have to download data from different server to the centos server in tbz format, then i have to extract it and after completion of the extraction i have to import data from it to mysql database table.

what i am doing is 
Getting data from the server which is around 700MB in size but when i am executing command to extract it and others nothing happens.

```
$files =   array('20111101.tbz', '20111101.tbz.md5' ,'20111102.tbz' ,'20111102.tbz.md5') ;

    //folder names of the folders formed
    $folder1 = "20111101";
    $folder3 = "20111102";

    //command to extract all the downloaded .tbz files
    $command1 = "cd /var/www/html/mywork1/mywork2/mywork3/";
    exec($command1." 2>&1", $output);
    $command2 = "tar -xjf ".$files[0];
    exec($command2." 2>&1", $output);
    $command4 = "tar -xjf ".$files[2];
    exec($command4." 2>&1", $output);

    //command to populate the data into the database
    $command6 = "cd /var/www/html/mywork1/mywork2/mywork3/mywork4";
    exec($command6." 2>&1", $output);
    $command7 = "./runit.py /var/www/html/mywork1/mywork2/mywork3/$folder1";
    exec($command7." 2>&1", $output);
    $command9 = "./runit.py /var/www/html/mywork1/mywork2/mywork3/$folder3";
    exec($command9." 2>&1", $output);

    //command to remove the folders created after population of data
    $command10 = "rm -rf $folder1";
    exec($command10." 2>&1", $output);
    $command11 = "rm -rf $folder3";
    exec($command11." 2>&1", $output);

    foreach ($files as $file) 
    {
        //command to remove all .tbz files downloaded.
        $command12 = "rm -rf $file";
        exec($command12." 2>&1", $output);
    }
```

i am simply executing the commands but its not doing anything. But when i try all these commands manually on server they work fine. Can any one guide me on this? What should be the correct approach to do this?

Comment: Your problem is, that you don't know what's going on. So please enable `display_errors`, set `error_reporting` to `-1`. Also display the output of the command after the `exec` (`echo $output;`). Does your Webservers user have write-access to those directories?

Comment: Not answering your question, but have you tried putting all those commands in a Bash script and just run that from your PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `exec("cd /some/dir");` as this would start a shell, which would go to this directory and then exit. For your PHP program it does nothing — working directory will not change.

You'd need to `chdir('/some/dir') or die("Cannot change directory");`.